# VS 2008 Under debug menu the "Save Dump As..." tab appearing many times

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 for a while now and i just noticed that under the "Debug" menu there are many disabled tabs of "Save Dump As...".
There are so many tabs like this that i can scroll the debug menu and it seems like i can't even reach the end of it all. I want to know why it is happening and how can i solve it.

[image: save dump as]

Comment: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > OK.

Comment: Great, but i don't want to reset my settings. Is there another way to do it? even manually. Also i  still don't understand why this is happening (i guess it can happen again...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find where i can edit this menu, in VS they call it "Commands".

Under "Tools->Customize->Rearrange commands..." select your current menu bar and remove the unnecessary command.

I still don't know why this is happening, but now it's easy to maintain.

You can also rearrange the menus as you wish, which is nice.